# Need a Concise Description on This Generic Typing

Tags: java, generics, methods, polymorphism, typing

I am studying for a Java course and my documentation gives this method header as generic example. Unfortunately, the description is lacking. Can someone explain what is going on with this typing?

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable <? super T>> T max(T a, T b) {
...
...
...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the generic typeparameter `T` should extends `Comparable`. `a` and `b` are of the type `T`. It only makes sense to get a maximum if the two paramaters can compared with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know,

```
<T extends Object & Comparable <? super T>>
```

is equivalent with:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

So, this says:

> `T`, which should be comparable to `T` or something that is abstracter than `T`.

This construction forces you to choose a T like `MyClass`, if `MyClass` is declared like one of these:

```
MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>
MyClass implements Comparable<MySuperClass>
MyClass implements Comparable<Object>
```

But doesn't allow:

```
MyClass implements Comparable<String>
MyClass implements Comparable<MyChildClass>
```

Given that: `MyChildClass extends MyClass extends MySuperClass extends Object`.